# Serial port access fails when Java app is Dockerized

Tags: java, linux, docker, dockerfile

My Spring Boot app uses the jSerialComm library (v2.6.0) to do serial comms over a USB port. The [jSerialComm documentation](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) notes the importance of adding the user to a number of groups:

> Note for Linux users: Serial port access is limited to certain users and groups in Linux. To enable user access, you must open a terminal and enter the following commands before jSerialComm will be able to access the ports on your system. Don't worry if some of the commands fail. All of these groups may not exist on every Linux distro. (Note, this process must only be done once for each user):
>
> > sudo usermod -a -G uucp username
> >
> > sudo usermod -a -G dialout username
> >
> > sudo usermod -a -G lock username
> >
> > sudo usermod -a -G tty username

So I wrote the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot

# Run application as non-root user to help to mitigate some risks
RUN groupadd -r spring && useradd -r spring -g spring && \
 usermod -a -G uucp spring && \
 usermod -a -G dialout spring && \
 usermod -a -G tty spring
# `lock` group doesn't seem to exist, hence commented-out:
# usermod -a -G lock spring
USER spring:spring

COPY /Java/tempctrl/build/libs/*.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

... and I include `--device=/dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0` (and, temporarily clutching at straws, `--privileged`) in the `docker run` command.

When the app starts, logging confirms that `/dev/ttyACM0` is found OK. But when the app tries to read from the serial port it receives continuous zeros. (Note: saw this a few times before moving the app to Docker and it was symptomatic of the USB port being already in use.)

If I comment-out `USER spring:spring` (i.e. allow the contained app to run as root) everything is fine.

How can I make this work without root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container-device#add-host-device-to-container---device), devices shared with `--device` seem to be root-owned (see image in link).

Perhaps you can try [`chown`ing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15384/how-to-chown-mounted-device)?

Comment: I can't find the reference that says devices shared with --device are root-owned, nor can I see an image. Did you post the right link?

Comment: yes, seems the hash part of the link is kinda broken, is on the add host device, where it runs `ls` on the `/dev` folder, all devices are root owned